# fglrx taking 100% of one cpu core

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I have a Acer Aspire V5-552G with a amd a10 apu (a10-5757m) and a dedicated hd 8750m graphics card. I installed the latest drivers from the amd website but my problem is that when i open certain apps(system settings,catalyst control center)one cpu core is at 100%. This happens only when under the catalyst center I select the "high performance gpu" the dedicated card. when I select the apu all works fine. I run Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. Sof for example if I open system settings, under system monitor the `unity-control-center` whici is system setting is going to take 25% of the cpu, and looking at the graph is always one core at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

It's a catalyst bug. It has been a year thet this bug exist and amd still doing nothing. I have same cpu but with 8970m. It affects all distro as I was an Ubuntu user now an Arch one. And others people from Gentoo are also complaining about it. Even latest Omega driver doesn't solve the bug. All you can do now, is crying because, the open source driver for `xorg` has great bug with DRI2 to use your discrete card and DRI3 is unsupported. So we have both to wait another year to have it working. I have already a post at AMD forum but nothing from the staff.

Have a nice New Year